# How can I implement O = Omit<T, keyof K> so that O & K is compatible with T

Tags: typescript, generics

The following snippet doesn't validate:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

function test<P extends { name: string }, R = Omit<P, 'name'>>(
    param: R,
): P {
    return {
        ...param,
        name: 'test'
    };
}
```

It produces the following error:

> type 'R & { name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'P'

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You will probably need a type assertion `...param as P`, typescript is very limited in what it can do with conditional types that still contain unresolved type parameters..

Comment: Thank you, managed to make it pass by adding `return {...} as unknown as P`. This is quite ugly, let's see if someone has a better solution.

Comment: Pretty sure this is unsolvable at present, but we'll see :)

Comment: This is a weird signature... there's no way to infer `P` from `param` and the value you have for `R` is just a default.  If I wanted something that behaved rationally I'd give the signature as something like `test<R>(param: R): Omit<R, 'name'> & {name: string}` (with `Omit<T,K>` redefined so that `K` is constrained only to `keyof any` instead of `keyof T`).  That wouldn't require any type assertions, but I don't know if that's what you want.